# Running Node.JS Project in multiple platforms

Tags: node.js, cross-platform

Can I run the same nodejs project which was created in Ubuntu in Windows also? or do I have to download the node modules again for windows? [My Node.JS project stopped working after changing into Windows from Ubuntu.]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: usually yes, but if there are any modules that require compiling you need to reinstall them.

Comment: No errors. I just can't connect to the server via browser. and it's not a firewall kind of a problem.

Comment: Why not? What happens? What error do you get from the browser?

Comment: "No data received". Server worked well in Ubuntu. I shall try downloading the node modules again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using modules with native components, you will need to re-install them so that they will be compiled against Ubuntu instead of Windows.

To simplify this, you shouldn't check your `node_modules` folder into git (add it to .gitignore).

This way, you can simply clone the repo on any system and run npm install, and everything will work fine.